# <sup> is not coming properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is HTML which will render the text with superscript value, the statement is rendering correctly, but second statement is not coming properly because `<sup>2</sup>` is outside the `<div>` tag, basically inside `<div>` tag html is generating dynamically and I am appending `<sup>` tag for each statement, but some of the value contains like the second statement that start with the `<div><p>` etc. tag so it does not render superscript value.

```
<div id="divDisclosure" class="disclosurelist">
<sup>1</sup>This is the first <u><strong>disclosure</strong></u>.<br>
<sup>2</sup>
<div>
    Test div asdf klasfjd sdklafj asdfasdf adsf sdafjhsd aklfjasdf kjasdfasd f sdavfg asdf asdf asdf sdaf sdf sda f asdf</div>
```

To resolving this I have written jquery like below

```
 jQuery('.disclosurelist').find('sup').each(function () {

    jQuery(this).prependTo(jQuery(this).next());
});
```

but now it is creating problem with first statement.

Comment: It *IS* rendering the superscript, but because of the `div`'s `block` display it appears as a next line.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: Why don't you simply put the `<sup>` inside the `<div>` where it belongs?? If you can't, for whatever strange reason, you can use some css, like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24uDJ/). (Maybe it will need some more specificity for more complex situations, but this works for this HTML.)

Comment: @Mr Lister, actually this data is coming from database, so some of the statement have <div> some have <p> or some tag doesn't have any tag like first statement in above html

Comment: @Irshad So does the fiddle help?

Comment: @Mr Lister, but what will happen if I have html like this  <div id="divDisclosure" class="disclosurelist">
<sup>1</sup>This is the first <u><strong>disclosure</strong></u>.<br>
<sup>2</sup>    
<div>
    Test div asdf klasfjd sdklafj asdfasdf adsf sdafjhsd aklfjasdf kjasdfasd f sdavfg asdf asdf asdf sdaf sdf sda f asdf</div>
    <sup>3</sup>   
<p>Test div asdf klasfjd sdklafj asdfasdf adsf sdafjhsd aklfjasdf kjasdfasd f sdavfg asdf asdf asdf sdaf sdf sda f asdf</p>
</div>

Comment: You can test for yourself. The fiddle is all yours.

Comment: I checked but it is not working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41705/discussion-between-irshad-and-mr-lister)

Answer (score 1):

just add second sup tag inside the div tag and then Test div asdf......